Problem with a query when comparing dates in Laravel based project
I'm working on apartments rental project. As a part of the applications abilities there is a functionality for an apartments owner to select days that the apartment is available for rental by guests. I'm writing a search query to get apartments where it checks amongst other things for days available for rental. I have following tables: rooms, bookings, days, day_room (pivot table). Since I'm new here please let me know if I need to post anything else for you to get a better understanding of my problem.
In this query when I would write static date like for example '2024-06-27' in the last Where method it would work just fine and produce desired results but when using $date->format('Y-m-d') it doesn't find anything. However in produced SQL query I don't see that there would be any difference, i.e. in dates format.
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use App\Models\Room;
    use App\Models\Booking;
    use Carbon\CarbonPeriod;
    use Carbon\Carbon;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

    class SearchController extends Controller
    {
        public function index()
        {
        // Validate data later

        $city = request('city');
        $guests_number = request('guests_number');
        $object_type = request('object_type');
        $checkIn = request('checkIn');
        $checkOut = request('checkOut');

        $interval = CarbonPeriod::create($checkIn, $checkOut);

        $rooms = Room::query()
            ->with(['photos', 'bookings', 'days'])
            ->where('rooms.city_id', '=', $city)
            ->where('rooms.beds_num', '>=', $guests_number)
            ->where('rooms.object_type_id', '=', $object_type)
            ->join('bookings', 'bookings.room_id', '=', 
              'rooms.id')
            ->where(function ($query) use ($checkIn, $checkOut) {
                $query->where('checkIn', '>=', $checkOut)
                    ->orWhere('checkOut', '<=', $checkIn);
            })
            ->whereExists(function ($query) use ($interval) {
                $query
                    ->from('day_room')
                    ->join('days', 'days.id', '=', 'day_room.day_id')
                    ->whereColumn('day_room.room_id', 'rooms.id')
                    ->where(function ($query) use ($interval) {
                        foreach ($interval as $date) {
                            $query->where('days.day', '=', $date->format('Y-m-d'));
                            // when testing if I write static date like here, then it works.
                            // $query->where('days.day', '=', '2024-06-27');
                        }
                    });
            })
            ->get('rooms.*');

        return view('results', ['rooms' => $rooms]);
    }


What dates you're taking as $checkIn and $checkOut? Does this includes the mentioned date? 2024-06-27

Instead of iterating over your $interval object, you should be able to use a whereBetween() clause. That being said, there shouldn't be any difference between $date->format('Y-m-d') and '2024-06-17', assuming one iteration of your $interval actually contains that date as Dhruv is suggesting.

Just pass the Carbon date object. Laravel is smart enough to convert it appropriately. Ensure you have correct casts on your model.

You could add ->ddRawSql() at the end to see the actual produced query. Which can be helpful for debugging and optimizing. Or use something like debugbar.
I think the issue is with the query, I believe you're trying to match multiple days.day on a single cell. Only one can be true, so when you hardcode only 1 date it will work

In the foreach you are inserting multiple where conditions related by the AND operator: the conditions will never be satisfied. You should use orWhere() instead but as suggested by @TimLewis a whereBetween() is a better choice.

@DhruvPandya, yes, when testing I was taking 2024-06-27 as $checkIn and 2024-06-29 as $checkOut. Both dates are available in the db table.

@TimLewis, I was trying different ways to use whereBetween() in my query none of which would produce the required result which is confusing to say the least.

@TimLewis, thank you. I'll edit the question and post the answer. Still new to stackoverflow. :)

No problem; welcome to SO  Also yeah, it's hard to say why whereBetween() wouldn't have worked for you, but ultimately if you've got a solution that produces the correct results, that's more important; optimization can come later. Cheers!

@TimLewis, thank you! I heard that Laravel had a great community but to get help firsthand feels amazing and really inspires me to learn more and work harder. You guys are amazing! Good luck in your projects!

Thank you all for your feedback in the comments section. @Rene and @Tupkap got me thinking in a right direction - I was checking for a multiple days.day against one cell. I fixed that by moving the foreach loop. Below is the edited version of the code that's working for me. I guess it's not the most elegant way to solve the problem but since apartments aren't ment to be booked for long periods (usually for a couple of days and no longer than 1-2 weeks).
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Room;
use App\Models\Booking;
use Carbon\CarbonPeriod;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class SearchController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        // Validate data later

        $city = request('city');
        $guests_number = request('guests_number');
        $object_type = request('object_type');
        $checkIn = request('checkIn');
        $checkOut = request('checkOut');

        $interval = CarbonPeriod::create($checkIn, $checkOut);

        $rooms = Room::query()
            ->with(['photos', 'bookings', 'days'])
            ->where('rooms.city_id', '=', $city)
            ->where('rooms.beds_num', '>=', $guests_number)
            ->where('rooms.object_type_id', '=', $object_type)
            ->join('bookings', 'bookings.room_id', '=', 'rooms.id')
            ->where(function ($query) use ($checkIn, $checkOut) {
                $query->where('checkIn', '>=', $checkOut)
                    ->orWhere('checkOut', '<=', $checkIn);
            })
            ->where(function ($query) use ($interval) {
                foreach ($interval as $date) {
                    $query->whereExists(function ($query) use ($date) {
                        $query
                            ->from('day_room')
                            ->join('days', 'days.id', '=', 'day_room.day_id')
                            ->whereColumn('day_room.room_id', 'rooms.id')
                            ->where('days.day', '=', $date->format('Y-m-d'));
                    });
                }
            })
            ->get('rooms.*');

        return view('results', ['rooms' => $rooms]);
    }

